# getInitialProps is not loading until page is refreshed in nextjs

Tags: javascript, cookies, next.js

I am using getInitialProps to get a server side cookie when the page loads. First user logs in and the cookie is set and I use a router.push() to send the user to the checkout page. When the checkout page loads it is not getting the initial props, but if I manually refresh the page then it works.

Here is what my getInitialProps looks like:

```
Cart.getInitialProps = async ({ req, res }) => {
    const token = parseCookies(req)
    
    if (res) {
        if (Object.keys(token).length === 0 && token.constructor === Object) {
          res.writeHead(301, { Location: "/" })
          res.end()
        }
      }
    
      return {
        token: token && token,
      }
    }
```

Then I am setting the token in the header so I can submit the order.

Comment: are you using router.push with `shallow : true` ?

Comment: Is `Cart` a page component?

Comment: Yes Cart is a page, I wasn't using shallow: true, but after I read the docs on it I switched it to use next/link instead of router.push and that solved it for now. Still not sure what was happening though.